# Is there a way to carry out 2 or more functions when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

This code is meant to print 2 values when a button is pressed

```
from tkinter import *

def func_1():
    print(100)

def func_2():
    print(200)

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=300)
btn = Button(root, text='click me', command=func_1 and func_2)
btn.pack()
```

Unfortunately, whenever the button is pressed, only the latter of the two functions is printed. What's wrong with the code and how do I get it to work?

Comment: Define a new function and call the two methods from inside the new function. Then call the new function with the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
from tkinter import *

def func_1():
    print(100)

def func_2():
    print(200)

def two_functions():
    func_1()
    func_2()

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=300)
btn = Button(root, text='click me', command=two_functions)
btn.pack()
```

You just call a single function which calls all functions you need.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are true, so `func_1 and func_2` is equivalent to just `func_2`. Just like `3.14 and 2.71` is equivalent to just `2.71`.

Another way to make it work, specifying the functions inline:

```
from tkinter import *

def func_1():
    print(100)

def func_2():
    print(200)

def call(*funcs):
    def doit():
        for func in funcs:
            func()
    return doit

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=300)
btn = Button(root, text='click me', command=call(func_1, func_2))
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `App(root).mainloop()` should be `root.mainloop()`.  There is no `App()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, fixed. When I tried the OP's code, nothing happened, so I took that `mainloop` thing from the `tkinter` documentation. I'm sure it worked then, and I copied&pasted the whole code into the answer. I'm also sure I didn't define `App` myself. Though I just tested again and indeed it didn't work with `App`. No idea how it worked before. Oh well.